# Is it possible to use Object Initializers on a bool?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-2.0, object-initializers

Is it possible to do the following (e.g. initialize bool array and set all elements to true) in one line using object initializers?

```
int weeks = 5;
bool[] weekSelected = new bool[weeks];
for (int i = 0; i < weeks; i++)
{
    weekSelected[i] = true;
}
```

I can't quite get it to work.

---

Edit: I should have mentioned that I am using VS2008 with .NET 2.0 (so Enumerable won't work).

Comment: Besides that the code doesn't work in current form you do have a typo, second line should be: bool[] weekSelected...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`bool[] weekSelected = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(i => true).ToArray();`

EDIT: If you can't use enumerable, you might be able to use a [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx):

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(count, true);
```

and then copy to an array as needed:

```
bool[] array = new bool[count];
bits.CopyTo(array, 0);
```

Comment: That's a great answers, but I am using .NET 2.0 with VS2008, so Enumerable does not exist there.  I updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using .NET 2.0, using a loop is the right way to do it. I wouldn't change it.

---

Original answer.

Your type declaration is wrong. Try this:

```
bool[] weekSelected = new bool[] { true, true, true, true, true };
```

You can also do this to avoid repeating yourself:

```
bool[] weekSelected = Enumerable.Repeat(true, 5).ToArray();
```

Note that this is not as efficient as a loop, but if you have say 100 values and performance is not critical, it's more concise than the loop and less typing than `{ true, true, true, ... }`.

Comment: With the initializer method, though, this doesn't allow you to pass in the size of the array

Comment: `weeks` is actually a variable.  I don't know ahead of time what the value will be. I should have made it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
bool[] weekSelected = Enumerable.Repeat<bool>(true, weeks).ToArray();
```